# Applying the Taylor's Theorem, show that if $x > 0$ then $|(1+x)^{1/3} - (1 + \frac x3 - {x^2\over 9})| \le {5x^3\over 81}$

Tags: real-analysis

I've been struggling with this problem for weeks now. Seeing as the Taylor's Theorem has up to n terms, I have no idea where to start or stop with it as I wasn't given a n to work with. Can I use the MVT? How would I use the MVT? I'm truly lost, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Taylor's theorem follows from the MVT (intermediate value theorem?). Try to use Taylor's theorem with $n=2$, $n=3$, and $n=4$ and $x_0 = 0$.

Comment: Would I apply it to the second half of the inequality? Edit: Wait no that wouldn't do much lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=(1+x)^{1/3}$. It is easy to verify that that the sum of the first three terms of the Taylor  expansion of $f(x)$ about $x=0$ is $1+\frac{x}{3}-\frac{x^2}{9}$.

Note that $f'''(x)=-\frac{10}{27}(1+x)^{-8/3}$.

By the *Lagrange form of the remainder*, the absolute value of the error when we truncate at the $x^2$ term in the Taylor expansion is
$$\frac{1}{3!}|f'''(c)| |x|^3,$$
where $c$ is between $0$ and $x$. In our case, that shows that the absolute value of the error is
$$\frac{1}{3!}\cdot \frac{10}{27}(1+c)^{-8/3}x^3.\tag{1}$$
Since $x$ is positive, $0\lt (1+c)^{-8/3}\lt 1$. The desired result now follows from (1).

*Remark:* The Lagrange form of the remainder **can** be proved using nothing more than the Mean Value Theorem. Probably, however, you are expected to just **use** the Lagrange form of the remainder, and not to prove it, even for this particular case.

Comment: How does knowing the remainder is less than 1 help? Edit: Wait I think I understand but I would still like clarification

Comment: There was a TeX error that I fixed. The error is equal to the expression (1), where $c$ is not known, but known to be between $0$ and $x$. So $1+c\gt 1$, and therefore $(1+c)^{-8/3}\lt 1$. Then from expression (1) for the error we have that the absolute value of the error is less than $(1/6)(10/27)(1)x^3$, which simplifies to $(5/81)x^3$.

Comment: Apologies for the typos. Having a bit of trouble with the TeX, I often can only see the source code, which makes proof-reading difficult.

Comment: @AndréNicolas.Lately I am having the same trouble with  the Tex. I found that  when it happens, if  I post, typos and all, and exit the Q, and re-enter it,  my A displays properly, but then if  I edit my A, I can  again only see the source code. Makes editing tedious.

Comment: @user254665:  Thanks. I will try reloading. The problem used to be infrequent, but for a while now it has been occurring often.

Answer (score -2):

**Hint:** Check the [remainder of alternating series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562091/taylor-series-approximation-for-degree-k-taylor-polynomial).

**Added:** In your case $f(x) = (1+x)^{1/3}$

> $$\Bigg| (1+x)^{1/3}-(1-x/3+x^2/9)\Bigg|\leq a_3$$

Where

> $$a_3=\frac{f^{(3)}(0)} {3!}x^3. $$

If calculate the third derivative of the function at $x=0$ you will get

> $$f^{(3)}(0)=\frac{10}{27}. $$

Comment: The task is to apply Taylor's Theorem.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp:I gave him exactly what he needs!  He needs to use Taylor series to compute some terms of the function he has first!

Comment: Ok. It depends on what he means by "Taylor's Theorem". If it's the quantitative version, your hint won't work.

Comment: To the OP make sure of your derivation! By the way do not worry about the downvote!!

Comment: OP see what I added.

Comment: This is misleading. The Taylor expansion is *not* an alternating series except when $x$ is small, which is not assumed here.

Comment: @Did you should save your useless comments!  Because users knows what's going on!!

Comment: OK. What about trying to correct your answer? I know, I know, the idea will sound strange to you at first, but, if ever you try to apply it, its benefits should soon become obvious...

Comment: @Did You are saying that the alternating series estimation applies only for $0\le x\le1$, right? Because that is where the series is both alternating and convergent?

Comment: @Braindead Exactly, the ratio of two successive coefficients of the series is something like $-\left(\frac{n-1/3}{n+1}\right)$, which is negative, as it should be, and which goes to $1$ in modulus, hence the conclusion you mention for every $0\leqslant x<1$ (and it happens that one can extend the result to $x=1$, looking more closely at the series then).

Comment: @Did: what's useless here is engaging someone so hostile to constructive criticism.  Meanwhile, the answer is still incorrect.